# Saving and read json_encode from database text field

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am trying to make chart for product detail page visit report, 1 row represent 1 day and increment for every visit for the same day. This script is part of, and actually it works :

```
var chartData = []; 

chartData  = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>; // array from db query

var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", { //.... and so on..
```

For some reason that 'I think' it would be so many rows for many products, So I just want to use a single row of table text field to store and hold data for one month period in JSON format. It means 1 row can store +/- 30 information.

I tried to store the json_encode object in database text field with ajax and JSON.stringify(). The stored data in text field is like this :

```
[{"date":"2018-06-24","visits":"510"},{"date":"2018-06-25","visits":"511"},
{"date":"2018-06-26","visits":"500"},{"date":"2018-06-27","visits":"508"},
{"date":"2018-06-28","visits":"509"}]
```

When I query this row, it returns array rather than a string. By using print_r() it return :

```
Array ( [data] => [{"date":"2018-06-24","visits":"510"},{"date":"2018-06-25","visits":"511"},{"date":"2018-06-26","visits":"500"},{"date":"2018-06-27","visits":"508"},{"date":"2018-06-28","visits":"509"}] [0] => [{"date":"2018-06-24","visits":"510"},{"date":"2018-06-25","visits":"511"},{"date":"2018-06-26","visits":"500"},{"date":"2018-06-27","visits":"508"},{"date":"2018-06-28","visits":"509"}] )
```

Questions :

1. How to fetch this data that stored in database and return it to JavaScript object. Why it returns an array rather than a string. I use json_decode() but it required a string. It was fail to use JSON.parse() to parse the data.
2. Is that a right way to do it so?

Any answer is appreciated.

Comment: The JSON data you have included in your question is returned by the server on ajax request and you want to access this JSON data in javascript? Is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, that what I want. So I can use it as data object to show the chart.

Comment: If `print_r` displays `[{"date"...}]`, then that *is* a string. A PHP array would display as `Array ( [date] => ... )`. Use `var_dump` to be sure about a value's type.

Comment: How do you actually "query this row"?

Answer (score 0):

See if your request is returning this as `string` (say in a variable called ***response***)

```
{"data" : [{"date":"2018-06-24","visits":"510"},{"date":"2018-06-25","visits":"511"},
{"date":"2018-06-26","visits":"500"},{"date":"2018-06-27","visits":"508"},
{"date":"2018-06-28","visits":"509"}]}
```

You first need to parse the string as JSON using:

```
let myobjects = JSON.parse(response);
```

Then you can access the elements by index, example:

```
alert(myobjects.data[0].date);
/* will display 2018-06-25 */

alert(myobjects.data[0].visits);
/* will display 510 */
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry, but when I query the data, it's return an array rather than string. Message :  Array to string conversion in... when print_r, data query it return : Array ( [data] => [{"date":"2018-06-24","visits":"510"},{"date":"2018-06-25","visits":"511"},{"date":"2018-06-26","visits":"500"},{"date":"2018-06-27","visits":"508"},{"date":"2018-06-28","visits":"509"}] [0] => [{"date":"2018-06-24","visits":"510"},{"date":"2018-06-25","visits":"511"},{"date":"2018-06-26","visits":"500"},{"date":"2018-06-27","visits":"508"},{"date":"2018-06-28","visits":"509"}] )

Comment: if `$data` is the array, use `json_encode($data);` to convert it into string.

Comment: Just saw you have updated your question, so according to that if `$row` is what your are printing with `print_r()` you need `json_encode($row->data);` to covert it into string.

Comment: json_encode result :{"data":"[{\"date\":\"2018-06-24\",\"visits\":\"510\"},{\"date\":\"2018-06-25\",\"visits\":\"511\"}.... so on...

Comment: Alright, use this `json_encode($row->data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);` . It will fix the slashes problem.